# SSH hanging after sending env LANG, only on one computer on network

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm unable to SSH into a server from one machine on my network. I can successfully SSH using the exact same port, address, user, and ssh key from other machines on my network. When I try to connect, half of my MOTD is printed out and then the connection hangs. I figured it might be an issue with my terminal reading the MOTD, but I've tried several different terminals with the WSL bash shell and the problem is consistent.

What could the issue be, or what would be the next step to diagnosing this?

The server is running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and OpenSSH 8.2p1

---

#### Desired

[image]

#### Actual

[image]

---

#### Successful Output

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to REDACTED ([REDACTED]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL = iTerm2
debug1: Sending env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = 3.3.7

                       _              _
 ___ _    ___   ___ | | ___   _  | | _____   
/ | '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| |/ / | | |/ _` |/ _ \ \ / /
\__ \ |_) | (_) | (_) |   <| |_| | (_| |  /\ V /
|___/ ./ \___/ \___/|_|\_\\__, |\__,_|\___| \_/
    |_|                     |___/

 Last login..........: root at Sat Apr 17 18:25 from REDACTED
```

#### Failure Output

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to REDACTED ([REDACTED]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8

                       _              _
 ___ _ __   ___   ___ | | ___   _  __| | _____   __
/ __| '_ \ / _ \ / _ \| |/ / | | |/ _` |/ _ \ \ / /
\__ \ |_) | (_) | (_) |   <| |_| | (_| |  __/\ V /
```

Comment: Try a different command (e.g. `ssh sapphire cat sample_file.txt`) to reduce the number of potential  causes. Observe whether the disconnect happens after a fixed number of bytes received (`timeout 10 ssh host command | wc -c`). Is my interpretation correct that connecting from a WSL-hosted client always fails, and the successful connection is unrelated to windows network stack?

Comment: What's with the downvotes? This is a valid problem, and apparently multiple people have been having the same problem according to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3438#issuecomment-410518578)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with WSL. As described in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3438#issuecomment-410518578), executing the following in Windows CMD solved the problem:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset all
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: thank you - this worked for me